# Filter a list of phone numbers in Google sheets based on the number NOT being in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with a list of telephone numbers which we ran an SMS campaign to (Sheet A)

Those that replied, I'd like to exclude from the next SMS campaign. So I imported the numbers that replied to another sheet (Sheet B).

I'd like to create a filtered list, or a new sheet which has only those numbers which didn't reply.

In SQL I'd prob use a `NOT IN` with an array of the numbers from Sheet B. However I have no idea how to do this in Google Sheets!

Both sheets just have 1 column with the telephone number in.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 2nd col to your sheet A, and use `Vlookup` (for example a formula like `=ISNA(Vlookup(A2,SheetB!A:A,1,False))`. Then you can easily filter your list (`FALSE` means the number is present in SheetB).